# Routing in PHP using the Flight framework

Tags: php, url-routing

I don't have any PHP framework experience and just have some pretty general questions regarding their use: specifically, URL routing.

I'm using the micro-framework, Flight.

Simple routing example:

```
<?php

    // Flight Framework
    require "flight/Flight.php";

    Flight::route('/', function(){
        echo 'hello world!';
    });

    Flight::start();

?>
```

When I visit this page (/), I get the 'hello world' message. Great, working fine.

My question is, is routing used for a URL that doesn't exist (e.g. /categories)? Then, when a user visits that page, the function would be called?

So if I changed the route to '/categories', shouldn't this 'hello world' function be displayed upon visiting /categories?

Comment: Have you tried just changing the route to /categories and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes, when I visit /categories, I'm instead taken to the index page instead of the function displaying

Comment: Okay, just figured it out. I didn't realize that the function had to be on the index page where the .htaccess file is. I was doing this in a different directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for what your expecting to work, you will need to have URL rewriting enabled. If your using apache as a web server using `Mod rewrite` enables you to accomplish this. When URLs are rewritten the web server routes all the none existing path urls to `index.php` and let index.php handle the request. Below is an example of such rewrite code placed in a `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, I've configured the .htaccess file for this according to the Flight installation guide

Answer (score 0):

When using Flight it's a whole lot easier to make use of PHP's internal web server. At least for testing purposes.

```
php -S <url>:<port>
```